# Does Google Calendar ignore event response?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, gcal

I'm developing a ASP.NET application which integrates with GMail API and Google Calendar API. It uses a GSuite account to manage calendar events and e-mails.

Basically the application sends e-mails, invitations to people creating calendar events and, if an attendee declines the invitation, the application unsubscribes the user from the event and deletes the invitation.

The issue: everything works fine if the attendee uses GMail, else the declination is not received:

- the attendee receives the invitation in GMail and selects "No" as response: the response is received
- the attendee receives the invitation in another mail client and clicks the "No" link inside the mail: the response is received
- the attendee receives the invitation in another mail client and rejects the invitation with any button provided by the mail client: the status in Google Calendar remains "awaiting response"

I found this behaviour using a standard GMail account too, so I suppose it does not depend on GSuite or my code. I googled a lot to see if this is a known issue, but I cannot find anything.

Does someone know if it is a known issue or there is any solution or any option to activate support for event responses?

Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT**

I finally found the following:

- the application creates a new calendar for managing its events -> invitations are managed as if they were from a different user and responses from attendees are sent to a xxxx_xxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com e-mail address instead of the user's e-mail address, so no mail in GMail, no attendee status changed
- using the primary calendar, I receive the event responses in GMail, but event attendee's status is not updated
- with the second approach, I will try to take actions on new mail messages too.

As much as I can understand Google only supports responses to events using the "Yes", "No" and "Maybe" links in invitation e-mails, but what if a user uses a mail client like Outlook, etc.???

Please note that not all users are smart enough to understand that a link has to be clicked instead of buttons provided by mail clients and, anyway, I would expect that it works too.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I edited my question with my findings. As I said in my question, it's not related to my code: you may reproduce this behaviour with any Google account with just GMail, Google Calendar and most desktop mail clients (Outlook, etc.).